# Load and perform data manipulation in shiny, with multiple click actions

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to build a shiny app, that has multiple things occur, click the go button, and data is loaded. when the data is loaded the slide bar should be updated with the min and max number of times the words appear.
When a word is entered in the remove input text box and button do is clicked, then the word is removed for the corpus, there is a similar action for a find and replace action, when this happens the graphs should be updated to show these changes.

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(sp)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)
library("stringi")
library(plyr)
library(dplyr) #Data manipulation (also included in the tidyverse package)


ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow( 
    column( 4, titlePanel("Twitter Analytics")),
    column( 3),
    column( 4, 
            textInput("searchstring", 
                      label = "",
                      value = "")),
    column(1, 
           br(),
           actionButton("action", "go"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column( 12, tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("one",
               fluidRow(
                 column(3, textInput("removeString", label = "remove", value = ""), actionButton("remove", "do"),
                        textInput("find", label = "find", value = ""),textInput("rep", label = "replace", value = ""),actionButton("replace", "act"), 
                        checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", "select plots",
                                           choices <- c("Histogram", "Wordcloud", "network")),
                        sliderInput("topTerms",
                                    label = "top (n) terms", 
                                    min = 0, max = 25, value = 0)  ),
                 column(9,fluidRow(column(12,plotOutput("ttext") )),

                          fluidRow(column(12,wordcloud2Output("wc2"))))
               )
      ),    
      tabPanel("two"),
      tabPanel("three")
    )
    )
  )
)




server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(go = 0, do = 0, act = 0 )


  observeEvent(input$action, {
    values$go <- 1
    values$do <- 0
    values$act <- 0

  })

  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    values$go <- 0
    values$do <- 1
    values$act <- 0
  })

  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    values$go <- 0
    values$do <- 0
    values$act <- 1
  })

  #tweet <- eventReactive(input$action,{
  tweet <-renderUI({

    if(values$go){

    num <- c(1,2,3,4,50)
    text <- c("this is love love something", "this is not hate hate hate something", "@something islove  rethched this not", " Shiny is love confusing me", "this is hate also somthing difficult")
    letter<- c("a", "b", "c", "D", "e")
    tweetdf <- data.frame(num, text, letter)
    tweetdf$text <- tolower(tweetdf$text)
    # tweetdf @UserName
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("@\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
    #remove punctuation
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", tweetdf$text)
    #remove links
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("http\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
    # Remove tabs
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("[ |\t]{2,}", "", tweetdf$text)
    # Remove blank spaces at the beginning
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("^ ", "", tweetdf$text)
    # Remove blank spaces at the end
    corpus <- iconv(tweetdf$text, to = "ASCII")
    corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus))
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
    cleanset <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))}

     if(values$do){

      cleanset <- tweet()
      cleanset <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, input$removeString)
     }

    if(values$act){

      cleanset <- tweet()
      cleanset <- tm_map(cleanset, gsub, 
                         pattern = input$find, 
                         replacement = input$rep)
    }

    else
      {return()}
  })



    output$ttext <- renderPlot({ 
      cleanset <-tweet()
      tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanset)
      tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
      w <- rowSums(tdm)
        library(RColorBrewer)
        barplot(w)

    })


    output$wc2 <- renderWordcloud2({
      library(wordcloud2)
      cleanset <-tweet()
      tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanset)
      tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
      w <- rowSums(tdm)
      w <- data.frame(names(w), w)
      colnames(w) <- c('word', 'freq')
      wordcloud2(w,
                 color = 'random-dark',
                 size = 0.7,
                 shape = 'circle',
                 rotateRatio = 0.5,
                 minSize = 1)
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

the code is representative of what I am trying to do but I have no idea where to go from here,

I get the following error message:

no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Comment: Your code seems really too broad, could you give us where you find it ?

Comment: Hi Remi, i am not sure what you mean by where i found it, i wrote that, based on my scant knowledge of Shiny